# What's the process "sugov:0"

Tags: process, raspberry-pi, armbian

I have an **Orange Pi** installed **Armbian**.

I find that when I use a CPU governor called `schedutil` a process called 
`sugov:0` will exist in `top`. And the `sugov:0` can spend about 13% CPU.

When I use the governor `ondemand` this process will not exist.

What's this process？
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Sugov is a kernel thread used in ARM architecture as part of the scheduling governor.

> the sugov kthread is a special RT task, which goal is just that to activate a frequency transition

As far as I can tell from the referenced documents the 13% CPU usage is a fake measurement and you needn't be worried about it.

It has a strange name so that `grep` can now easily find all its references in the kernel source without being overwhelmed by false matches.

References

- https://lwn.net/Articles/740546/
- https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/806725/

Comment: SchedUling GOVernor. There was a proposed patch in 2017. Seems like it didnt make it into the kernel or the OP isnt up to date.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't able to find out very much about it